# Jetson Xavier NX + Intel AX210NGW WIFI 6E 6Ghz

Tags: wireless-networking, ubuntu-20.04, wpa-supplicant, nvidia, intel

my setup:

- Jetson Xavier NX, Jetpack 5.1.1, ubuntu 20.04, linux kernel 5.10
- Intel AX210NGW WIFI 6E 6Ghz
- Router netgear RAXE300 tri-band

situation:
I was able to connect to wifi 6ghz from my laptop running the same Ubuntu 20.04 and the same wifi card.
I then tried to do the same with the Jetson, I was able to follow all the tutorials with the expected results until at the end where I'm unable to see the 6ghz network from the Jetson.
I’m able to connect to 5ghz and 2.4ghz networks from the jetson with the same wifi card, just don't see 6ghz.

software limitations:
I'm unable to upgrade the linux version or firmware due to the jetpack version being already the latest.
I'm aware wifi 6ghz is plug and play with ubuntu 22, but I'm unable to install it.

software modifications i've made:

- upgraded wpa-supplicant from 2.9 to 2.10, to enable 6ghz band
- upgraded linux wifi band registry to latest available (2023-05-03), to enable 6ghz band
- disabled Network Manager, to avoid conflict with wpa_supplicant

Tutorials followed to do so:

- [raspberry wifi 6ghz tutorial](https://dev.to/wataniguchi/how-to-build-a-6ghz-wifi-client-with-a-raspberry-pi-and-netgear-a8000-47ok)
- [ubuntu wifi 6ghz tutorial](https://medium.com/@barry_wu.me/how-to-connect-wi-fi-6e-ap-over-the-6-ghz-band-with-ubuntu-21-04-2a0b4f071ac2)
- [disabling of Network Manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091653/how-do-i-disable-network-manager-permanently)
- [how to use wpa_supplicant](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Wpa_supplicant#Connecting_with_wpa_cli)

Comment: There's a a direct upgrade path between LTS releases. Have you tried to release upgrade your 20.04 to 22.04? If so what was the result?